# Ajax calls, sending images and other data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was wondering is there a length limit for it?
Im sending images and some data to my server, but it returns that it cannot "find" the required data. Sometimes it can and sometimes it cant find it.
And it is getting really frustrating because I cant find the problem. Im sending the images as an dataURL.
The server gets nothing. Its like there was an empty formData but by checking the inspection tool the data is writen correctly.

Any other things i could check?

Posting code:

```
var ID = this.id.substr(11);

        if (!user) {
            if (document.getElementById('userName').value.length < 1) {
                Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterName')}}', true);
                $('#userName').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#userName').addClass('has-error');
                return;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('userPhone').value < 1) {
                Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterPhone')}}', true);
                $('#userPhone').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#userPhone').addClass('has-error');
                return;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('userCity').value < 1) {
                Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterCity')}}', true);
                $('#userCity').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#userCity').addClass('has-error');
                return;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('userEmail').value < 1) {
                Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterEmail')}}', true);
                $('#userEmail').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#userEmail').addClass('has-error');
                return;
            }
        }

        if (document.getElementById('price-' + ID).value.length < 1) {
            Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterPrice')}}', true);
            $('#price-' + ID).parent().addClass('has-error');
            $('#price-' + ID).addClass('has-error');
            return;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('description-' + ID).value.length < 1) {
            Listing.alert('{{trans('adsAdd.enterDescription')}}', true);
            $('#description-' + ID).parent().addClass('has-error');
            $('#description-' + ID).addClass('has-error');
            return;
        }

        var formData = new FormData();
        var images = [];

        $('#img-div-' + ID).find('.img-outer-div').each(function (index, imgElement) {
            var img = $(imgElement).find('.item-image');
            images.push(img.attr('src'));
        });

        formData.append('images', JSON.stringify(images));
        formData.append('category', document.getElementById('category-' + ID).options[document.getElementById('category-' + ID).selectedIndex].text);
        formData.append('price', document.getElementById('price-' + ID).value);


        formData.append('description', document.getElementById('description-' + ID).value);
        formData.append('time', document.getElementById('time-' + ID).selectedIndex);
        formData.append('type', (document.getElementById('type-' + ID) != null) ? document.getElementById('type-' + ID).selectedIndex : 0);
        formData.append('lang', '{{App::getLocale()}}');
        if (!user) {
            formData.append('userName', document.getElementById('userName').value);
            formData.append('userPhone', document.getElementById('userPhone').value);
            formData.append('userCity', document.getElementById('userCity').value);
            formData.append('userEmail', document.getElementById('userEmail').value);
        }
        formData.append('id', ID);

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'true');

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open('post', '/items/add');
        req.send(formData);

        req.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(req.response);

            if (obj['message'] != null) {
                if (obj['message']['email']) {
                    Listing.alert(obj['message']['email'], false);
                } else if (obj['message']['phone']) {
                    Listing.alert(obj['message']['phone'], false);
                } else if (obj['message']) {
                    Listing.alert(obj['message'], false);
                }
            }

            var id = obj['id'];
            var item = $('#item-' + id);

            if (obj['success']) {
                item.empty();
                item.append('<div class="alert alert-box" id="alert">{{trans('adsAdd.done')}}</div>');
                item.fadeOut(4000);

                if (!user) {
                    window.location.replace("{{URL::route('home-index')}}");
                }
            } else {
                item.find('button').prop('disabled', null);
                item.find('button').innerHTML = '{{trans('adsAdd.send')}}';
            }
        });

        this.innerHTML = '{{trans('adsAdd.sending')}}';
```

And php code:

```
$message = null; // Message for user

    $locale = Input::get('lang');

    // Item
    $data = array(
        'category' => Input::get('category'),
        'price' => Input::get('price'),
        'description' => Input::get('description'),
        'images' => json_decode(Input::get('images')),
        'time' => Input::get('time'),
        'type' => (Input::get('type') == null) ? 0 : Input::get('type'),
    );


    $validator = Validator::make($data, array(
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'images' => 'required|max:10',
        'time' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
    ));

    if($validator->fails()) {           
        return Response::json(['success' => false, 'message' => $validator->errors()->first()]);
    }
```

It only gets to the part where the validator fails. If it dosnt fail, and the data is actualy sent to the server it saves it and all is good.

If it helps I can give a link to the webpage where it can be checked out.

EDIT-------------
So it seems that some pictures cannot be sent. Individualy and with others. And some pictures can be sent individualy but not together with other. And some pictures can be sent individualy and with other pictures that can be sent. This is really really weird.

Comment: The maximum size of `POST` data and maximum size of uploaded files is a per-server configuration setting.

Comment: I checked and it shouldnt be the problem. Any other things i could check?

Comment: Please post your code. Also, look in the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what you're sending in the AJAX request.

Comment: As I said, Im sending the correct data. But sure, ill post the code.

Comment: It could be a security module that's stripping your request body because of the image urls you're sending.

Comment: @Musa But wouldn't that mean that it always those that? The ajax calls sometimes get through to the server and the server processes the data corectly. Thats why im getting so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the true answer is what actually @Barmar said. I looked at the size of files I'm sending and it seemed alright, but what I didn't think about was that I didn't send the images as files but as data-URL. And that means that the file size didn't matter. And I had to actually increase the actual post size.